# Cache data may be lost when replacing the getPosts field of a Query object. Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-server

I am setting up my button to like posts. Is shows basic if not liked and shows colored when liked. But a when a single user likes and post he cannot unlike it and the number of likes keep on incrementing in the like counter and cannot return to basic. Please help me out. How can I set to user unlike the post after clicking on liked post.
This is my code:

```js
function LikeButton({
  user,
  post: {
    id,
    likeCount,
    likes
  }
}) {
  const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user && likes.find((like) => like.username === user.username)) {
      setLiked(true);
    } else setLiked(false);
  }, [user, likes]);

  const [likePost] = useMutation(LIKE_POST_MUTATION, {
    variables: {
      postId: id
    }
  });

  const likeButton = user ? (
    liked ? ( <
      Button color = "black" >
      <
      Icon name = "heart" / >
      <
      /Button>
    ) : ( <
      Button color = "black"
      basic >
      <
      Icon name = "heart" / >
      <
      /Button>
    )
  ) : ( <
    Button as = {
      Link
    }
    to = "/login"
    color = "black"
    basic >
    <
    Icon name = "heart" / >
    <
    /Button>
  );

  return ( <
    Button as = 'div'
    labelPosition = 'right'
    onClick = {
      likePost
    } > {
      likeButton
    } <
    Label basic color = 'black'
    pointing = 'left' > {
      likeCount
    } <
    /Label> <
    /Button>
  )
}

const LIKE_POST_MUTATION = gql `
    mutation likePost($postId: ID!){
        likePost(postId : $postId){
            id
            likes{
                id username
            }
            likeCount
        }
    }
`

export default LikeButton;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const cache: new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    getPosts: {
      likes: {
        merge(existing, incoming, {
          mergeObjects
        }) {
          // Correct, thanks to invoking nested merge functions.
          return mergeObjects(existing, incoming);
        }
      }
    }

  }
})
```